Dynamic slide in PPTXGENJS
Can we add new slides dynamically using pptxgenjs if the slide is not declared* in the project?
*pptx.addSlide('MASTER_SLIDE');
I want to check if I can add new slides to a PPT even though it is not declared in the code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
